# How do screenshots work in the app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm coming from Android development with Google Play where every screenshot you upload (for small res to high res to tablets) were available for viewing regardless of which device/platform you're viewing the app listing page from.

I just launched my first iOS App Store app and it seems this is not the case.

> If I view the App Store listing on my desktop, I only see the iPhone
>   4-inch screenshot I uploaded.
>
> If I view the App Store listing on my iPhone 5s I also only see the
>   iPhone 4-inch screenshot.

I was assuming it was going to be like Google Play where I can see all of the available screenshots regardless of which device/platform I was on.

---

Anyway, this is bad for me since I uploaded different screenshots for each device size/type and uploaded 4 very important screenshots only to the iPhone 4.7-inch category.

Here are my questions:

- Is the iPhone 4-inch the "default" screenshots to show, for example - when viewing the app listing on a desktop computer?
- Is it good practice to upload the same bunch of screenshots to every single size category?  This is what I feel I need to do.

Comment: Yes, and yes (provided the screenshots for each category were taken on the appropriate device/simulator).

Comment: Cool, thanks, that's what I though, just wanted someone else to confirm.  I just found out that I need to submit a new binary and go through that process in order to update screenshots though.  Apple sure knows how to keep things interesting, I'll give them that.

Comment: unless your app is already in review or has already been reviewed, you should be able to change the screenshots and metadata. Once it goes into review you're locked out, though.

Answer (score 0):

- Is the iPhone 4-inch the "default" screenshots to show, for example - when viewing the app listing on a desktop computer?

  - Yes
- Is it good practice to upload the same bunch of screenshots to every single size category? This is what I feel I need to do.

  - The screenshots required should only reflect what the app can support.

Here is Apple's docs regarding the screenshots and requirements: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2

I've spent way too time in that document lately :)